# Is there a way to index two mongo collection in to one in ElasticSearch?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I have two collections called Books and Authors in MongoDB.
I am indexing these two in to ElasticSearch.

I want to denormalize just in ElasticSearch so that my search/filter becomes easier. That is, I want to have Book and Author as one document in ElasticSearch.

Is this possible with mongoosastic or is there any work around to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this can be achieved using mongostatic. I can explain a pure Elasticsearch option for this and an easy one. You can easily use nested objects and build a document such as

```
{
"book": "Lord of the rings",
"author": {
        "name": "Tolkien",
        "bio": "..."
    } 
}
```